# how to add new column with string and distribute it perfectly along number of rows in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of data frame:

```
no    id       size  type a complete   type a incomplete   type b complete   type b incomplete   type c complete   type c incomplete

1    shoes     270      1                    2                 0                  0                  1                  1
2    shoes     275      2                    2                 1                  0                  0                  1
```

and I want to simplify the data frame like below:

```
no    id      size    type       status           value
1    shoes    270      a         complete          1
1    shoes    270      a         incomplete        2
1    shoes    270      b         complete          0
1    shoes    270      b         incomplete        0
1    shoes    270      c         complete          1
1    shoes    270      c         incomplete        1
2    shoes    275      a         complete          2
2    shoes    275      a         incomplete        2
2    shoes    275      b         complete          1
2    shoes    275      b         incomplete        0
2    shoes    275      c         complete          0
2    shoes    275      c         incomplete        1
```

what I have tried so far was doing df.melt first to get the "type" column like this way:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars = ['no', 'id', 'size'], var_name = 'type', value_name = 'value').sort_values('no')
```

then make "status" column and distribute it manually:

```
status = ['complete', 'incomplete']

df['status'] = (df.index % len(status)).map(dict(enumerate(status)))
```

but it did not give me the perfect desired table as I expect.

Is there any other way I can do to get the expected table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert tot splitted columns to `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then split columns names by space with remove first level (`type` string) by [`MultiIndex.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) for 2 levels `MultiIndex in columns`, add columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with convert `Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['no','id','size'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True).droplevel(0)
df = (df.rename_axis(['type','status'], axis=1)
        .stack([0,1], dropna=False)
        .reset_index(name='value'))
print (df)
    no     id  size type      status  value
0    1  shoes   270    a    complete      1
1    1  shoes   270    a  incomplete      2
2    1  shoes   270    b    complete      0
3    1  shoes   270    b  incomplete      0
4    1  shoes   270    c    complete      1
5    1  shoes   270    c  incomplete      1
6    2  shoes   275    a    complete      2
7    2  shoes   275    a  incomplete      2
8    2  shoes   275    b    complete      1
9    2  shoes   275    b  incomplete      0
10   2  shoes   275    c    complete      0
11   2  shoes   275    c  incomplete      1
```

Comment: thank you so much! this answer helps me a lot. But is this script directly remove the row with NaN value?

Comment: @nomnomyang - yes, for prevent it add `dropna=False` to `stack()`